# Why is my host displaying 2 cron processes?

Tags: process, cron, ps

I notice that I am getting 2 different cron processes in `ps`:

```
[user@host ~]$ ps aux | grep -i cron
500        746  0.0  0.0   6384   676 pts/1    S+   13:40   0:00 grep -i cron
root       905  0.0  0.0  20408  1036 ?        Ss    2019  54:54 crond
root     30406  0.0  0.1  39152  1672 ?        S    Feb14   0:00 CROND
smmsp    30429  0.0  0.2  76424  3820 ?        S    Feb14   0:00 /usr/sbin/sendmail -FCronDaemon -i -odi -oem -oi -t -f root
```

I have also a zombie process that has `30406` as it's parent:

```
[user@host ~]$ ps -A -ostat,ppid | grep -e '[zZ]'| awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq | xargs ps -p                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
30406 ?        00:00:00 crond
```

What is this second `CROND` process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CROND is a child process of crond; it gets created when a crontab entry is processed.

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i cron
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY      TIME     CMD
root        2289       1  0 Feb12 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/crond -n
root      446475    2289  0 14:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/CROND -n
```

Process # 2289 (crond) is the parent process for 446475 (CROND).